# c# How to Split a string with Json data inside

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, split

I saved the Json datas in a string and separate with commas, how can I split them because if I use string.Split(",") it will separate the Json data too.

Comment: Minimum viable example please, let's not do guess work of what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: I think your best option is to preppend a '[' and append a ']' into the string, this way turning you data into a Json array. Then, you can deserialize the value into an object array.

Comment: `I saved the Json datas in a string` It sounds like you might be confused on how that is supposed to be done

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using some other character to separate your strings, preferrably one that won't appear within JSON. ("|", maybe?)